# Using ValidateOnBuild flag in .net 6.0 with WebApplication.CreateBuilder

Tags: .net, .net-6.0

I am trying to validate if DI dependencies can be resolved using the ValidateOnBuild flag. So far, I am failing to do so.

I am using a sample application with

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
var app = builder.Build();
```

Where should I set this flag in order for validation to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Host.UseDefaultServiceProvider(o =>
{
    o.ValidateOnBuild = true;
    o.ValidateScopes = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();
```